# Cant connect to database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, yaml, dropwizard

I'm trying to connect to my database when I start my server in drop wizard. But I get the following error when I try to start the server

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl: HHH000342: 
Could not obtain connection to query metadata : 
Driver:org.h2.Driver@7ed6a46e returned null for 
URL:jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDatabase
```

Here is the code for my .yml (yaml) file

```
     # Database settings. 
   database:

     # the name of your JDBC driver   
     driverClass: org.h2.Driver

     # the username   
     user: root

     # the password   
     password: superSecretPassword

     # the JDBC URL   
     url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDatabase
   server:
     type: simple
     connector:
         type: http
         port: 8080
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Is the Database Server started?

Comment: Yes it is started. But the problem was with the driverClass mentioned below

Comment: Had to add mysql-connector-java to Maven to get it resolved. Jamil Rahi's comment to Jens's reply gave a clue. Thank you Jamil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a wrong JDBC- Driver class: `org.h2.Driver` You have to use a mysql driver like `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot. That was the mayor problem. + that i did not add mysql to my maven dependency when i first tried that url you mentioned